# can't handle size of a popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I want to create a popup menu like in foursquare in swift2, x-code 7.3:

[image]

I'm using this code

```
//Create Pop up Menu
func setAnimatedMenu(identifier : String)-> ViewController{

    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(
        name: "Main",
        bundle: nil)
    let menuViewController: ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as! ViewController//filters

    menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen //played with this and tried every different styles
    menuViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height/3) //Played with this size, nothing changes

    let popoverMenuViewController = menuViewController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self

    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = parentViewController?.view
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = CGRect(
        x: self.view.frame.size.width,
        y: self.view.frame.size.height/3,
        width: 1,
        height: 1) //played also with this size, nothing changes


    return menuViewController

}
```

What I would like to accomplish is something like in the picture, a pop up over the current view and tabs but with 1/3 of the upper view visible. I only have managed to do over full screen and I only can see the back view if I do scroll in the pop up and move it to bottom or top.

I try to set its `preferredContentSize` but the property is unmutable:

[image]

These are the storyboard properties:

[image]
[image]

EDIT: I managed to fix it, I hadn't realized that there were constraints in storyboard setting the window size. I have created an outlet of the height constraint, and just changing it's value from the code it has fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Y position is the position of where its located on a Y axis so you need to set this to:

```
y: (self.view.frame.size.height/3) * 2.0,
```

Comment: Does exactly the same as before. Nothing has changed. Can be the issue in storyboard? Edited to add storyboard images with properties